# Storing references to components created at runtime

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Given the following Blazor component:

```
@foreach (var col in columns)
{
    @foreach (row in rows)
    {
        <MyInput @onkeydown="KeyDown" @ref="NewInput"></MyInput>
    }
}

@code {
    private List<MyInput> inputs = new List<MyInput>();

    private MyInput NewInput
    {
        get { return _NewInput; }
        set
        {
            _NewInput = value;
            inputs.Add(_NewInput);
        }
    }
    MyInput _NewInput;

    private async Task KeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Code == "ArrowDown")
        {
            //TODO: Find out which dynamic MyInput-instance
            //      within the inputs collection triggered the event
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add cursor navigation between the MyInputs using the arrow keys. For this to work, I obviously need to know which MyInput component triggered the key-event.

I managed to store all MyInput instances into a List by abusing the @ref property, but I can't figure out which instance within my list triggered the event.

Does Blazor offer any way to find out which dynamically created MyInput-instance triggered the event?

Comment: Uhm... it seems to me that there's only one `_NewInput` object that you keep adding over and over again to the list. That's not going to work. You're not actually carrying new objects...

Comment: @JHBonarius I know it seems odd, but that's in fact the recommended (or only) way to add dynamic component instances to a list. I found it on another post somehwere, don't remember now. Fact is: That's not the problem, the debugger shows that all individual instances are correctly added to the collection.

Comment: PS: There's another approach for storing references, but I don't think it will help much in identifying the event trigger: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17361

Comment: Couldn't you just add a reference to the input in the event handler, as in the second example in the "lambda expressions" section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0#lambda-expressions)?

Comment: Can you show us what `MyInput` looks like?  Also you can't call `@onkeydown=KeyDown` on a component without defining onkeydown as a EventCallback.  It's not a Html element.  At which point you can provide a unique reference to the component instance - say a GUID and look it up in the inputs collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you've defined a component named"

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<div>@ID.ToString()</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int ID { get; set; }

}
```

Which has a parameter property ID, provided by the parent component, like this:

### ParentComponent.razor

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <ChildComponent @ref="component" ID="i" />
}

@code
{
    private ChildComponent component { set => components.Add(value); }

    List<ChildComponent> components = new List<ChildComponent>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(component.ID);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you can identify the component by its ID. A simple and effective way, though you may do that in other ways.

Note: This is wrong:

```
<MyInput @onkeydown="KeyDown" @ref="NewInput"></MyInput>
```

because you assign the name of a method, the "KeyDown", to the @onkeydown compiler directive, which is only applicable to Html tags, not to component.

You can do something like this:

```
<MyInput ID="id" @ref="NewInput"></MyInput>
```

ID should be a parameter property defined in MyInput component, which is a child component, mind you. You also have to define an EventCallback which should be triggered from an event handler for the `keydown` event. In the cuurent case the EventCallback should return to the parent component, the ID of the child component in whose html tag, say an input html element, the `keydown` event occurs. I hope you succeed to get what I'm saying... if not, don't hesitate to ask questions.

UPDATE:

Note: I've added some code to my previous code sample to demonstrate how to return the ID of each ChildComponent when you hit the KeyDown button of an input Html element embedded in each child component. Additionally, my code also demonstrate how to return a reference to each component when its KeyDown event takes place:

### ChildComponent.razor

```
<input type="text" @onkeydown="@KeyDown" />

       
@code {

    [Parameter]
    public int ID { get; set; }

   // [Parameter]
   // public EventCallback<int> CallBack { get; set; }

  
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<ChildComponent> CallBack { get; set; }

     private void KeyDown(KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {
      //  if (args.Code == "ArrowDown")
      //  {
      //      InvokeAsync(() => { CallBack.InvokeAsync(ID); });
      //  }

        if (args.Code == "ArrowDown")
        {
            InvokeAsync(() => { CallBack.InvokeAsync(this); });
        }
    }

}
```

### ParentComponent.razor

```
<div>@output</div>

@for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <ChildComponent CallBack="ShowID" @ref="component" ID="i" />
}


@code
{
    private ChildComponent component { set => components.Add(value); }

    List<ChildComponent> components = new List<ChildComponent>();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        foreach (var component in components)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(component.ID);
        }
    }

    private string output = "";

    // private void ShowID(int id)
    // {
    //     output = id.ToString();
    // }


    private void ShowID(ChildComponent child)
    {
        output = child.ID.ToString(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: As an addon to @enet s updated answer, you can use a Guid as the ID to give you a unique reference for the specific instance of MyInput.  If you return `this` as suggested and need access to `KeyboardEventArgs` you can expose it as a public property on the component and set it on each `KeyDown`.

Comment: @enet thanks a lot, this guided me in the right direction. Abour your onkeydown remark: I'm aware of this, however the component I'm using is called "MudInputString", it's a wrapped html input. It does in fact support the onkeydown, so that would be fine in my case. I just tried to decouple my sample for the question. Thanks so much!

Comment: What I don't understand is Microsoft's argument for not providing a sender in Blazor events. I think that's a lame excuse. When you inspect Blazor-generated HTML, you'll notice that almost every DOM element is referenced by a unique Blazor Id. Surely this could be translated back to the original component to which the DOM element belongs. But we'll have to live with this limitation for now.